# Which linux command is trustable about file encoding guess, file or nkf?

Tags: linux, encoding, utf-8

File encoding result is different by nkf and file. Which is trustable?

```
$ nkf -g test
EUC-JP

$ file -I test
test: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

This is the file content.

```
$ cat test
Móviles
```

So, I converted its encoding to utf-8 with nkf and got garbling characters.

```
$ nkf -w test
M坦viles
```

So, this file seems **EUC-JP**. But why **file** command show it as **utf-8**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For guessing the file encoding there is no perfect way to do it as this answer shows it:**
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11648

**For converting the file try this**

```
iconv -f ENCODING_IN -t ENCODING_OUT(UTF-8) FILE_IN > FILE_OUT
```

Comment: I'd like to know **ENCODING_IN** at first to know the current encoding. That's why I use **$ file -i** and **$ nkf -g**.

Comment: Oh, there is no perfect way... That's what I'd like to know. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry about this :/ Although if the input file is html or xml they will have their incoding specified, not sure if that helps though. Please mark this question as solved :)